# How to find number of resources associated with Amazon VPC in .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am in need to find the number of resources associated with Amazon VPC in .Net

I have searched about the various `describe` methods for VPC which return different types of values including `Tags` etc. but I am not able to find the same.

Below are the number of resources which I am trying to find associated with given Amazon VPC-Id

> Number of RDS DB Instances
>
> Number of Auto Scaling Groups
>
> Number of EC2 Instances
>
> Number of ElastiCache Clusters
>
> Number of Elastic Beanstalk Applications
>
> Number of Elastic Load Balancers
>
> Number of Elastic MapReduce Jobs
>
> Number of Redshift Clusters

If anybody has any idea on this then please help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to query each of those services separately.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the reply. can you please give the example for one of the above resources?

Comment: @VickyKhichar, I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to query each individual service for resources attached to a given VPC. The VPC doesn't really keeps tracks attached to it. The only thing VPC knows about resources is ENIs, but you can't know what service ENI is attached to.

Here is an example how to get EC2s in VPC.

```
        AWSCredentials credentials = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials();
        var client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
        var res = client.DescribeInstances(new DescribeInstancesRequest()
        {
            Filters = new List<Filter> {
                new Filter {
                    Name = "network-interface.vpc-id",
                    Values = new List<string>{"THIS_IS_VPC_ID"}
                }
            }
        });
        foreach (var reservation in res.Reservations)
        {
            foreach (var instance in reservation.Instances)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(instance.InstanceId);
            }
        }
```

If a service API doesn't provide VPC specific filter you have to query all instances yourself and filter on VPC ID, for example for RDS:

```
        var rds = new AmazonRDSClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

        var rdsRes = rds.DescribeDBInstances();
        foreach (var instance in rdsRes.DBInstances)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(instance.DBSubnetGroup.VpcId);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. That helped to find the number of instances within a VPC. 
Can you please tell me different filter values to find other resources like Number of RDS DB Instances, Auto Scaling Groups Number of EC2 Instances, etc.

Comment: @VickyKhichar it all depends on the service, each service has its own list of filters and response structures. I added generic example for RDS. You can also try to use tagging, you tag resources that live in the same VPC and then you can get all resources with the same tag value relatively easily.